# Copy last modified files from network path into SQL server box and rename them using Agent job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, xp-cmdshell

I have to copy latest backup from a network path and bring that to my SQL server physical drive for restore, I have to do that using agent job.

This is what i am doing.

Created a SQL server agent job

1) XCOPY source *.bak /Y destination < **This copies all the files, but I need the latest file** >
2) Ren *bak mydbbackup.bak <**added this into step 2 of job **>

Questions:

*What mistake am i doing here ?*

*Are there any xcopy **/**commands which can copy the latest files only and ignore old files ?

Is there a way i can do that using another SQLCMD command besides creating a stored procedure*

Thanks,
learner

Comment: Did you try to get the latest full backup file name, the destination form system tables? [Script to retrieve SQL Server database backup history and no backups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/)

Comment: yes, its good t sql...but my case is to copy the latest files and restore them in test server .

Comment: Agent jobs can run PowerShell scripts.  Instead of using a cmdexec step or TSQL+xp_cmdshell, write a PowerShell script that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, But i am a newbie found a thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457249/find-latest-file-name-and-copy-as-renamed-file-in-the-same-folder but not sure how to modify it as per my requirement,

Comment: $OriginalDir = "\\XXXXX\YYYYY_backup\OOOO-NNN-DB01\XY_UUUUU\FULL"
$BackupDir = "\\DEVSQLSERVER\XY_UUUUU_FULL"
#After the -Name can be changed for whatever you need to backup.
$LatestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir - *.bak | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
Copy-Item -path "$OriginalDir\$LatestFile" "$BackupDir\$LatestFile"
........................................................................................................................................
this looks idiotic :(

Comment: $source = 'XXXXX'
$destination = 'YYYYY'
@(Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.bak | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0] | % { Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination `'$("$destination\GGGGGG.bak")`' -force}

i am getting error in T SQL AGENT JOB 

Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(3): Syntax error).  The step failed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around :

I have created ps1 file using the script below....
.
.
.
$source = ''
$destination = ''

@(Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.bak | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0] | % { Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination $("$destination\CMSOPEN_backup.bak") -force} 
.
.
.

and then, created bat file which calls this ps1 file, went to sql agent job, created step to execute the bat file later executed the t sql for restore.

Comment: You could launch the PowerShell script directly from your SQL Agent job step (instead of calling the file from a cmd step)

Answer (score 0):

/d parameter on xcopy with no date specified will copy over only new files that don't yet exist in the destination.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy